# Unix - How to convert octal escape sequences via pipe

Tags: bash, unix, utf-8, octal

I'm pulling data from a file (in this case an exim mail log) and often it saves characters in an escaped octal sequence like \NNN where 'N' represents an octal value 0-7.  This mainly happens when the subject is written in non-Latin characters (Arabic for example).

My goal is to find the cleanest way to convert these octal characters to display correctly in my utf-8 enabled terminal, specifically in 'less' as there is the potential for lots of output.

The best approach I have found so far is as follows:

```
arbitrary_stream | { while read -r temp; do printf %b "$temp\n"; done } | less
```

This seems to work pretty well, however I would assume that there is some translator tool, or maybe even a flag built into 'less' to handle this.  I also found that if you use something like sed to inject a 0 after each \, you can store it as a variable, then use 'echo -e $data' however this was more messy than the previous solution.

Test case:

```
octalvar="\342\202\254"
```

expected output in less:
€

I'm looking for something cleaner, more complete or just better than my above solution in the form of either:

```
echo $octalvar | do_something | less
```

or

```
echo $octalvar | less --some_magic_flag
```

Any suggestions?  Or is my solution about as clean as I can expect?

Comment: Is every character in octal format?

Comment: No, it's a mix of normal text and escaped octals

Comment: Your solution is probs the best you are gonna get then, less doesn't have a flag convert octal to ascii. Maybe change to `while IFS= read -r temp` to preserve spaces.

Comment: I was actually trying to convert to utf-8 but yeah.

My only problem with this solution is that my 'arbitrary output' has some whitespace at the beginning of each line that dosn't work well with my 'while read -r' witchcraft as 'read' ignores un-quoted whitespace.

This is what prompted me to ask.

I found a solution by injecting a \" at the beginning and end of each line before piping to the read bit, then trimming the quotations after the conversion, but my OCD hates it.

Comment: Ah that was actually my main problem :)  I'll try that out.  Thanks!

Comment: One issue to consider: can you distinguish between the user typing out this question in their mail message and actual octal escapes inserted by the mail agent?  If you can't tell the difference, are you sure it is safe/wise to unencode it, especially if the original may not have been UTF-8?

Comment: Not sure.  The subject line is clearly marked in the log like 
    T="Some subject that may contain octals" 
and I am actually stripping out the subject before running the conversion in my case using awk with a regular expression.

So in theory, the only information that should be input into this is extracted from either the authentication field (ie username or dovecot login) or the subject field.

Is there security implications with converting them in this way?

Comment: Just in case you were curious my application here is spam monitoring... the subject line and its relative frequency are good indicators that the mail is spam.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler How could it be unsafe?

Comment: @user1869743 If you are just comparing subject lines/analysing frequency do you really need to convert the octal chars?

Comment: Various ways — and it depends on your definition of 'unsafe' and how the mapped information will be processed.  For example, `\301\251\270` contains an invalid byte (`\301` is hex C1, which is never valid in UTF-8), and the `\251` and `\270` bytes are continuation bytes not preceded by a valid 'start-of-code-point' byte.  What happens when those are converted back to the raw bytes?  They're invalid UTF-8.  That's the primary issue.  You could also have people trying to get shell script executed and other such tricks if you post-process the converted data inappropriately.  Just be cautious.

Comment: I meant glancing over subject lines and how often they are sent out.

i'm using a combination of sort and uniq -c to count the frequency of each subject line from each user/email.  When you see a user sending out 20 different subjects, each containing octals,  I'd like to have a general idea of what is being sent, if nothing else an idea of the language.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I assume that simply piping any output, valid or garbage to something like 'less' would have almost no chance of executing any of the contained text.  As long as I'm not doing something crazy like piping anything to 'eval' or other such dangerous command, I shouldn't have any trouble, but I can't say I'm an expert in Linux security by any standard.

Comment: You're likely to be OK — that's why I couched it as an "issue to consider" rather than "something that you must deal with".  You'll have to decide whether the way `less` handles invalid UTF-8 data is OK.  You'll also have to consider whether terminal escape sequences piped to `less` could screw things up.  Probably not, but funnier things have been known, especially in the days of actual green-screen VDUs (visual display units), as opposed to terminal windows on laptops, etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler probably wise to strip out any invalid utf8 with someting like: iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -c
that way less doesn't have to be trusted to know how to take out the trash.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler less displays control chars as carets.

Answer (score 2):

Conversion in GNU awk (for using `strtonum`). It proved out to be a hassle so the code is a mess and maybe could be streamlined, feel free to advice:

```
awk '{
    while(match($0,/\\[0-8]{3}/)) {  # search for \NNNs
        o=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)  # extract it
        sub(/\\/,"0",o)              # replace \ with 0 for strtonum
        c=sprintf("%c",strtonum(o))  # convert to a character
        sub(/\\[0-8]{3}/,c)          # replace the \NNN with the char
    }
}1' foo > bar
```

or paste the code between single quotes to a file `above_program.awk` and run it like `awk -f above_program.awk foo > bar`. Test file `foo`:

```
test 123 \342\202\254
```

Run it in a non-UTF8 locale, I used locale C:

```
$ locale 
...
LC_ALL=C
$ awk -f above_program.awk foo
test 123 €
```

If you run it a UTF8 locale, conversion will happen:

```
$ locale
...
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8
$ awk -f above_program.awk foo
test 123 â¬
```

Comment: Locale is important. Also, terminating with `1` does `print $0` which adds a newline char, best to use `printf $0`.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current version:

```
echo $arbitrary | { IFS=$'\n'; while read -r temp; do printf %b "$temp\n"; done; unset IFS; } | iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -c | less
```