# Format xargs output to grep

Tags: linux, bash, grep, xargs, xattr

I have a script that I'm trying to optimize with `xargs`. The current version uses `find` with `-exec` to call the command:

`find -type f -iname "*.mp4" -print0 -printf '\n' -exec getfattr -d --absolute-names {} \;`

after which I can pipe to `grep` with something like:

`grep -z -P user\.md5\=\"$input_search_hash\"`

to filter the results while keeping the whole output with `-z`.

I need the whole output returned from `getfattr` to be "preserved", per file, because I need the filename for which there is a matching extended attribute, which then is then passed to `sed` to extract it. There are also cases where I have multiple `grep` commands in sequence if I need to search for files with *multiple* matches in the extended attributes. The problem is that the output of:

`find -type f -iname "*.mp4" -print0 | xargs -0 getfattr -d --absolute-names`

is not formatted in such a way that `grep` will filter in this way. This *does* work with the `-exec` method. Can I pass an addional option to `xargs` or pipe in some additional command that will format the output to make grep properly replicate the behaviour of `-exec`? I'm guessing I need some sort of line-break before feeding to `grep` like what `-printf '\n'` does in the `-exec` method. I would just use `getfattr` to "search" the extended attributes instead of needing to `grep` the output at all, but it has no way to do this by suppling a xattr name and value.

## Example

The input comes from the `find` command, which is a list of video files in an arbitrary directory structure. The output of each `getfattr` command, for each file is such:

```
# file: /path/to/file/test.mp4
user.md5="0e29a7f555af518872771689e28d998d"
user.quality="10"
user.sha256="d49ba58e3b30f4ef8c81d19ce960edcf6552977bb8adb79b5b9a677ba9a54b2b"
user.size="1645645"
```

If I attempt to `grep` the output of `find` using the `+` method, say for a value of "10" on the quality, I will get results like this:

```
# file: /path/to/file/test.mp4
user.md5="8cf97b888e6fdbed27b02233cd6779f5"
user.quality="12"
user.sha256="613d16b2a0270e2e5f81cfd58b1eacf710a65b82ce2dab49a1e415275440f429"
user.size="1645645"

# file: /path/to/file/test1.mp4
user.md5="3c5a39f1ceefce1e124bcd6786a99155"
user.quality="10"
user.sha256="0d7128a7642d24ea879bbfb3de812b7939b618d8af639f07d5104c954c8049c3"
user.size="5674567"

# file: /path/to/file/test2.mp4
user.md5="0e29a7f555af518872771689e28d998d"
user.quality="6"
user.sha256="d49ba58e3b30f4ef8c81d19ce960edcf6552977bb8adb79b5b9a677ba9a54b2b"
user.size="15645"
```

*All* files that `find` locates are returned and the string to be searched from `grep`, in this example `user.quality="10"`, is highlighted, but the other files test.mp4 and test2.mp4 still have the output printed post-grep. In other words, `find` may locate 1000 mp4 files of which maybe 20 have a `user.quality="10"` entry, but even applying `grep` to search for that string still returns 1000 filenames (after `sed`).

This *does not* happen when using `\;`. The only thing I would get out from `grep` would be:

```
# file: /path/to/file/test.mp4
user.md5="3c5a39f1ceefce1e124bcd6786a99155"
user.quality="10"
user.sha256="0d7128a7642d24ea879bbfb3de812b7939b618d8af639f07d5104c954c8049c3"
user.size="5674567"
```

This is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Can you add an example with expected input (directory structure) and expected output?

Comment: I added an example of what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### `xargs` vs `find -exec`

To me it seems like you want to use `xargs` instead of `find -exec {} \;` to speed things up.

Yes, `xargs` is faster than `find -exec {} \;`, not because it does the same work more efficiently, but because it does different work!

- `find -exec {} \;` calls once for each file (`getfattr file1`, then `getfattr file2`, and so on).
- `xargs` crams as many files into one call as possible (`getfattr file1 file2 file3 ...`).
  The same behavior (and even more speedup) can be achieved with `find -exec {} +` -- no need to use `xargs` for that.

With `xargs` and `find -exec {} +` you loose control over the output format. There is only one call of `getfattr` so that program decides what to print between `file1`, `file2` and so on. `getfattr` has no option to customize its output format.

No problem! You can ...

#### Parse `getfattr`'s output

... pretty easily.
<sub>For starters, we assume that all path names are pretty normal. Spaces, `*`, and `?` are ok though. For really unusual path names containing backslashes and linebreaks see the last section.</sub>

If you output only the relevant attribute using `-n user.md5` instead of `-d`, then you know that the output (if any) for each file is always of the form

```
# file: path in a single line
user.md5=encoded value of the attribute
```

Files without the attribute `user.md5` are not printed at all. They cause a warning on `stderr` which can be suppressed by `2> /dev/null`.

Now, grep for matching attributes. Use `grep -B1` to print the line above each match (i.e. the path) too. Then use `sed -n` or `grep -o` to extract the filenames.

```
find -type f -iname '*.mp4' -exec getfattr -n user.md5 --absolute-names {} + 2> /dev/null |
grep -B1 -Fx "user.md5=\"$input_search_hash\"" |
sed -n 's/^# file: //p'
```

Above command prints the paths of all mp4 files having the attribute `user.md5` with value `$input_search_hash`.

#### Handling Unusual Filenames

At least my version ([`getfattr 2.4.48` by Andreas Gruenbacher](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/attr/)) on Debian 10 always prints the file name in a single line. Linebreaks are encoded using `\012` and backslashes are encoded using `\134`. Therefore, safe processing of those files is possible.

Above command works, but prints only the encoded file names. To get the actual filenames you have to extend the `sed` command or add another command to [interpret octal escape sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43461003/6770384). For me, `getfattr` only escapes `\n`, `\r` and `\\`, thus `sed 's:\\012:\n:g;s:\\015:\r:g;s:\\134:\\:g'` should be sufficient for printing. For further processing, you may want to use `tr \\n \\0 | sed -z ...` instead, such that filenames are separated by null bytes.

To test which characters are escaped for you, create a filename containing all allowed bytes and let `getfattr` print its name:

```
f=$(printf $(printf '\\%o' $(seq 1 255)) | tr -d /)
touch "$f"
setfattr -n user.md5 -v 123 "$f"
getfattr -n user.md5  "$f"
rm "$f"
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that, while the speed increase is massive, it will still only work for a single attribute. If you require filtering on more than one attribute, the slower `\;` method must be used due to the limitations of `getfattr`.

Comment: No, even when filtering multiple attributes you still can use `find -exec getfattr -d ... +`. You just have to adapt your filtering-logic. `getfattr` is relatively easy to parse safely.